# DNS hosted zone not taking effect - AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have recently transferred my domain name trademarklawexplained.com from One.com to AWS.

I have the following set-up in Route53:

[image: Route53 Hosted Zone set-up]

For some reason, none of my records (SOA, NS and A) have had any effect. [trademarklawexplained.com](http://trademarklawexplained.com) does not map to [35.176.22.92](http://35.176.22.92), nor does it even look at the name server (I tested it with [this tool](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/dnsLookup))

Have I set up my hosted zone incorrectly, should I somehow publish it, or is the issue with One.com?

If someone could point me in the right direction to troubleshoot it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say you have transferred the domain is it you transferred domain renewal and entire domain registration to route53? or only pointing to route 53 Name Servers?

Comment: I transferred domain renewal and entire domain to Route53.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out in the end…

For a name server to be associated with a Route53 hosted zone, do the following:

1. Create a Hosted zone for your domain name. Note the NS record.
2. Go to *Registered Domains* > *example.com* > *Add or edit name servers* > Add the name servers from step 1.

[image: Select your registered domain on AWS Route53]
[image: Edit name servers]

When transferring a domain to AWS, it keeps the old NS record. Make sure to change it as per step 2.

Comment: This answer is still current as of Nov 2020. If you happen to delete, edit or change your hosted zone, Route 53 will NOT update the Name Servers automatically.

Comment: Is it safe to leave your records out there in the open? I have watched YouTube videos and they seem to blur out these info, I'm guessing they're sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the records it is still pointing to old records.

You need to update the DNS servers with your domain registrar for it to take effect.

If the DNS servers are updated, you might need to wait for the TTL time defined with the previous registrar to expire. DNS servers can cache those records until that TTL time defined in those NS records.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the DNS settings in the hosted zone, but not in the *Registered Domains* panel. Solved it now.

Answer (score 0):

How long have you waited? DNS records have a TTL (Time To Live). DNS servers around the world will cache your domain records until the TTL expires. For example, in your screenshot the TTL for your Name Servers is 172800 seconds which is 48 hours. In general it takes two or three days for the Internet to start caching your new domain records, sometimes longer. If it has been more than a week, then there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have encountered a similar issue, i had to wait for about 2 days to get the A record have a correct routing. However, the A record of alias type to the load-balancer works almost immediately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).