# transferred registrar/dns to route53, site has been down over 48hours

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

In the process of transferring all domains I manage to Route53. 
I transferred domain (sayyes.com) from NetworkSolutions, apparently they didn't transfer the zone file so the site went down (every other registrar +has+ transferred the zone file without issue btw).

I created a new zone, added the domain and created an NS record for the domain from 4 addresses I got from the new zone.

I created an MX record with the google values for email. email is sending but not receiving.

I have an A record in there pointing the domain to the correct IP. The IP is working when I ping it directly.

It's been over 48hours, I still see no changes. I've pinged whatsmydns.com and it's all red x's.

I called my old registrar (networksolutions) and they said there's nothing they can do, not even transfer the site back (because I made changes they must wait 60 days).

Help!

Answer (score 0):

ugh figured it out.

saw this post:
[DNS hosted zone not taking effect - AWS Route53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435715/dns-hosted-zone-not-taking-effect-aws-route53)

So i changed the nameservers in the hosted zone, and in the domain within the hosted zone, BUT you really need to click on registered domains and change it in there. looks like it's starting to propagate now.